# solving equations in sas

Tags: sas, equation-solving

Is there a function in sas 9.4 similar to solve function in matlab that I can use for solving equations:

```
syms x sig1 sig2 mu1 mu2;

solve(1/sig1/sqrt(2*pi) * exp(-1/2*((x-mu1)/sig1)^2) == 1/sig2/sqrt(2*pi) * exp(-1/2*((x-mu2)/sig2)^2), x)
```

Or what would be the most effective way to find intersection point of 2 or more lines in sas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation solving is possible in several different environments in SAS.

- FCMP: The [SOLVE](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1xoknqns865t7n1wehj6xarwhdb.htm) function allows you to solve a previously defined function.
- PROC MODEL: The [SOLVE] (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_model_sect006.htm) statement allows you to solve a series of NLE for some value(s) when the value of other variable(s) are given.
- IML: The [SOLVE](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/63541/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_tutorial_sect002.htm) function can again solve a system of equations, given its representation in matrix form.